# Mapreduce on big gz file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, bzip2, gzip

I have a big gz file of size around 120GB. I want to run mapreduce on that, but as gz file is not splittable, only one mapper is able to process that file at once. The file is present at hdfs and local both.
Possible option I am thinking:

1) Decompress that gz file and store it in hdfs: Firstly it will take too much time to decompress the file and to put the decompress data in hdfs. Also I cannot decompress the file directly in hdfs as hdfs don't have zcat or gunzip command. So I have to do `zcat a.gz | hdfs dfs put - /path/in/hdfs` .
Also this will take so much space in hdfs (approx 4 times more than gz)

2)  split the file in small file(around 1GB each) and do processing on them: Best option,but unfortunately not working. I am splitting the big file into small files using split command(also tried cat a.gz | head -n),but when I am running mapper on them I am getting error

```
Error: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of input stream
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.decompress(DecompressorStream.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.read(DecompressorStream.java:85)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.fillBuffer(LineReader.java:180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.nextKeyValue(LineRecordReader.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:553)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:784)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1642)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
```

3) decompress the file and then compress again into bzip2: Also it will take to much time.

Please suggest me any other idea to achieve this or to modify any of the above three methods to get the success(I prefer 2nd method :P)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can go with option 3. Compressing the file in Bzip2 gives the advantage of using it directly in the mapreduce job. Since Bzip2 is splittable, you dont need to split it manually into 1GB files (as in your option2) and do processing on them, hadoop anyway have to store them into blocks of specified size and process on the input splits configured. So, doing a pre-processing of compressing the file into Bzip2 should work fine.